# Per-site inauthentic usage policy links to MSE for referencing standards (as opposed to per-site pages)

Tags: bug, status-review, hyperlinks, help-center, code-of-conduct

I've picked two sites here - Magento and Aviation as examples.

Each site, linked from the per-site CoC, has an inauthentic usage policy. At the end of the policy, it has a link to referencing standards [in context of plagiarism].

See, for example:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage

The `Acceptable use` link (at the top) links to a per-site page, but the last bulleted item containing a link to "referencing standards" always goes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Can that link be replaced with a per-site link, so, for example, on Aviation SE, it would go to `https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/referencing` instead of the MSE version?

Comment: Note to editor: I see why other tags may also fit, but due to the five tag limit, I'd like to leave space for a status-something tag

Comment: @Shadow Also, the [tag:meta] tag is for questions about Meta.SE itself - the bug isn't on Meta.SE itself (in fact it works exactly as intended on here), so that tag doesn't apply here.